# Descargar archivo Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, base64

Mi servicio me retorna un b64 de imagenes. Alguna forma de decodificar el b64, convertir a archivo y descargar el archivo en angular. Algun ejemplo que me puedan proporcionar.

Comment: Hola, por favor repasa la sección de ayuda: [ask]. También puedes revisar [mcve]. Si crees que puedes corregir tu pregunta puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un elemento `<a>` con el atributo `download` en la vista y luego simular el clic, o puedes hacer un binding al atributo que sea igual al href en base 64.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<a class="button nav_link" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,11" download="">Descargar Imagen</a>

<div ng-app>
<p>Copia el base64, Ejemplo: data:image/jpeg;base64,11</p>
<input ng-model="value" />
<br/>
<a class="button nav_link" ng-href="{{value}}" download="">Descargar Imagen {{value}} </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte...